# Word like plagiarism

Tags: single-word-requests

Plagiarism is using other peoples work as yours.

If someone does your work instead of you, but you claim it's yours, i.e., someone writes part of your thesis for you, they didn't publish it elswere or write it as a part of their work that you copied, just did it for you, would there be another word to describe that?

Comment: Sort of ghost writer?

Comment: @Hachi well yes, but for the act the person claiming to do the work does. So second person is doing ghost writing but the first person is claiming that work is theirs, I need a word for that

Comment: I think that the person who publishes a book with the help of a ghost writer is simply called “the author”

Comment: But if you're not writing a book, you're writing a thesis, phd disertation, homework, or something else that should show your skill/knowledge?
Or even for a book, should "the author" be eligible for rewards for literature just for being able to hire someone who doesn't know the quality of their work?

Comment: That’s a different question. Most famous writers around the world use ghost writers as far as I know. And there nothing illegal about it. Ghost writers are paid to do their job and to remain  “invisible”. See https://www.quora.com/Do-ghostwriters-ever-get-credit-for-their-work-Under-what-circumstances

Comment: [Plagiarism](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plagiarism) on Academia SE may be helpful.

Comment: Cheating. Fraud, Misrepresentation, False attribution

Comment: After reading the question and all of the comments, I have no idea what you're actually looking for, if it's not the nouns *ghost writer* or *author*. A ghost writer does the writing, but the author is the person who (per a legal agreement—so this is *not* a case of anything nefarious) approves the content, takes credit for it, and represents themselves as the author.

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm looking for a word that describes an author that highers a ghost writer in context where it's not allowed to have one, in homeworks and thesis that should generaly be written by the author. I would like to know if there's a specific word for that kind of cheating or academic missconduct, or does it fit into plagiarism. All the words Alan wrote describe it but much more too

Comment: Ghost writing is not illegal, nor is it plagiarism. At best, in the scenario you describe, it would be against the policies of the publisher (or the person or institution) receiving the work. Exactly which word to use would be dependent on the *intentions* of the person who submits the piece of writing—and whether or not they *say* they've used a ghost writer anyway, despite the policy not to.

Comment: But of the words suggested by @Alan it's really only *cheating* and *fraud* that might fit in general. But, more specifically, it would be something like *deception*, assuming they did it anyway and are trying to get away with it. If they weren't aware of a "no ghost writing" policy, it would be a simple *oversight* or *mistake*. From the perspective of the receiving party, it could be considered a *policy violation*.

Comment: Is it reasonable to think that someone wouldn't be aware they shouldn't pay someone else to do their homework?

Comment: @Affaltar I don't see why not. Naive people do things all the time. Somebody, knowing that ghost writers exist, could easily hire somebody to write something on their behalf, and then submit the manuscript to a publisher. (If it were accepted, the situation would likely be discovered—especially if the person had to sign a contract that said they wrote the material themself.) But I don't see why such an innocent mistake couldn't be made. But if you're concerned with homework *only*, that's something different. Anybody who submits a thesis should be more aware of institutional guidelines.

Comment: Yeah, I'm concerned with homeworks, essay type exams and undergraduate thesis types, not peer reviewed papers published in journals. So if I understand correctly it's not plagiarism, it's just a type of cheating/policy violation with no specific word for it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no good alternative for *plagiarism* in an academic context, where the school or college usually has a code of conduct that requires a student to present his/her own work. Whether the provider is willing, paid, or simply a passive source, it’s still plagiarism. The professor can flunk the student in the course (I’ve done it myself); the school administration may impose other penalties, e.g. expulsion.

> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plagiarize
>
> plagiarize verb
>
> pla·​gia·​rize | \ ˈplā-jə-ˌrīz  also -jē-ə- \ plagiarized;
>   plagiarizing
>
> Definition of plagiarize
>
> transitive verb
>
> : to steal and pass off (the ideas or words of another) as one's own :
>   use (another's production) without crediting the source
>
> intransitive verb
>
> : to commit literary theft : present as new and original an idea or
>   product derived from an existing source
>
> MW goes on to note:
>
> Plagiarize (and plagiarism) comes from the Latin plagiarius
>   “kidnapper.” This word, derived from the Latin plaga (“a net used by
>   hunters to catch game”), extended its meaning in Latin to include a
>   person who stole the words, rather than the children, of another.

Synonyms all have the same negative connotation:

> Synonyms

infringement.
piracy.
appropriation.
borrowing.
fraud.
stealing.
theft.
counterfeiting.

From Thesaurus.com